# On a infinite series problem of IMC

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contest-math

In the solution 2 of problem of 2 of [IMC 1999](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc1999/prob_sol1.pdf)

I want to ask why $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi (n)}{n^2}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\pi (1)+ \pi(2)+\cdots + \pi(n))\left( \frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$$ ? I tried to prove it but have failed. Is the same true if I replace $\pi (n)$ by any function and replace $1/n^2$ by any function that telescope? I think this equality is true for infinite series only, it is false for finite series. Is it a standard technique in math competition? thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh is this "proof" correct:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi(1)+\cdots+\pi(n)}{n^2}- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi(1)+\cdots+\pi(n)}{(n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi(1)+\cdots+\pi(n)}{n^2}- \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\pi(1)+\cdots+\pi(n-1)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi(1)}{1^2}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\pi (n)}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi (n)}{n^2} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}(\pi (1)+ \pi(2)+\cdots + \pi(n))\left( \frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)=$$
$$\pi(1) \left(\sum_{n=1}^{m} ( \frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}) \right)+\pi(2) \left(\sum_{n=2}^{m} (\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}) \right) +...+\pi(m)\left(\frac{1}{m^2}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^2} \right)= $$
$$=\sum_{j=1}^m \pi(j) \left(\sum_{n=j}^{m} ( \frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}) \right)$$
$$=\sum_{j=1}^m \pi(j) \left( \frac{1}{j^2}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^2} \right)$$

It is obvious that

$$\sum_{j=1}^m \pi(j) \left( \frac{1}{j^2}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^2} \right) \leq \sum_{j=1}^m \pi(j)  \frac{1}{j^2} $$

To prove equality, all you need is to observe that for $N < < m$ we have

$$\sum_{j=1}^m \pi(j) \left( \frac{1}{j^2}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^2} \right) \geq \sum_{j=1}^N \pi(j) \left( \frac{1}{j^2}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^2} \right) $$

Now, fix $N$ and send $m \to infty$. Then you get

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \pi(j) \left( \frac{1}{j^2}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^2} \right) \geq \sum_{j=1}^N \pi(j)  \frac{1}{j^2} $$

and from here you can get

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \pi(j) \left( \frac{1}{j^2}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^2} \right) \geq \sum_{j=1}^\infty \pi(j)  \frac{1}{j^2}$$

The argument seems to hold under pretty general requirements, note that the positivity is also important in the last part. You need all series to be positive and convergent.